# What does RJS stand for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What do the letters RJS stand for? Is it as simple as Rails Java Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's Ruby Javascript. But it's the simple. Sometimes, it's referred to as "Ruby-enhanced JavaScript" or "JavaScript with/enhanced by Ruby".

Comment: Or even "JavaScript with embedded ruby" according to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: That's a new one for me, but I wouldn't be surprised. Apparently, "RJS" is what most people call it and very few actually define what RJS actually stands for.